# Pointer (mouse touchpad or touchscreen) click event not working in Win 8.1

Tags: windows-8, mouse, touchpad

So, my win 8.1 laptop click is malfunctioning, but in a very weird way:

- I can click icons in the desktop, i can drag to create boxes (update now i can't).
- I can use chrome freely. BUT
- I can't click to interact with anything, not with the touchpad nor touchscreen.
- I can't click anything in the metro interface, but i can touch stuff.
- If i click a window, focus switches OUT, as if i was clicking outside

Has anyone experienced this or even fixed it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This leads me to ask these questions: Do you have a wireless mouse? Is there any kind of anti virus software installed?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious - restarting your PC?

Comment: Yes, i restarted several times the mouse is wireless and cheap, my first guess is to blame the driver.
It has never happened again because i got a new mouse. If the bug was driver dependant, then it's not that interesting.